# Magento block remove on specific cms page through local.xml

Tags: xml, magento

is it possible to remove, lets say block with name links only on specific cms pages through local.xml. This way I could save time un-setting block on specific cms pages through Magento admin.

I'm thinking something like this.

```
<reference name="left">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <pageId>1</pageId>
        <pageId>15</pageId>
        <pageId>23</pageId>
        <name>links</name>
    </cmsPagesId>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

Goto  `Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php` find function `_renderPage()`

```
if ($renderLayout) {
                   // add code here 
            if(in_array($pageId,array(1,15,23))){
            $action->getLayout()->unsetBlock('left');
            }
            $action->renderLayout();
        }
```

Comment: Change core files? Why?

Comment: No sense doing this in the core files.

Comment: janhocever then craete a model and rewrite that helper class and function.